# How to handle custom headers in OPTIONS request

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, axios, preflight

What I am trying to get is to send a custom header through a request to an API. I have my react app as the client and a express app as the service. In my service, I am setting this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, my-custom-header',
  );
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH');
  next();
});
```

And in my react app, I am using axios to consume the service like this:

```
const callEndpoint = (dataToPost) =>
 axios.post(
   {
     `${my-url}/{my-endpoint}`,
     { dataToPost },
     { headers: { 'my-custom-header': 'anyStringValue' },
   }
 ).then((res) => handleRes(res))
  .catch((err) => handleErr(err));
```

However, every time I call `callEndpoint(dataToPost)` I am getting this error from CORS in the preflight:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-url/my-endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:PORT' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field my-custom-header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I thought adding `my-custom-header` in the service configurations would allow me to proceed but it did not. I also tried setting `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'` but did not work either.

I also tried using `cors` package like this:

```
const corsOptions = function (req, callback) {
  callback(null, { allowedHeaders: '*' })
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

But when tested locally, I did not get the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` in the response headers. So, I did not even deployed this piece of code to the server.

What should I do to allow my custom header to pass CORS in the preflight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the cors plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors. It will handle cors request for you

Comment: @elvis_ferns I also used `cors` package, and set `allowedHeaders: '*'`. But got the same result. Let me update my question so you can see how I set it.

Comment: @elvis_ferns there you go.

Comment: no need for a special config. it will take the headers from the request headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**refer below**

```
//if you want to add cors app level  
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes

//if you want to add cors single rout level
app.options('/products/:id', cors())
app.del('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
```

Comment: its not to avoid, its for adding to all or specific routes

Comment: @elvis_ferns i changed the typo